# Using LINQ to order or sort list and output into list box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

I am trying to separate a text file into 4 columns (comma delimited) and read it in using Streamreader and then find the most popular occurance of the first column and have it output into a listbox.

I have tried the LINQ suggestions online but I think the issue is between reading the text file in and the format it is in when I try and sort it.

I have a list of places and I want the one that occurs most in the list. When I just output the list unordered it outputs into the listbox.

The error I am gettin is ''char' does not have a definition for 'col''?

The input file for example:
Name,Age,DOB,Male
Anne,28,01/01/1991,False
Anne,29,06/06/1989,False
John,18,06/07/2000,True

And I want to output: 'Anne' into the listbox:

```
private void btnPopularCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"R:\Data.txt");
            string line = string.Empty;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                lstMostPopularCourse.ClearSelected();
                string[] col = line.Split(',');

                var sort = line.GroupBy(item => item.col[0]);

                var popular = sort.OrderByDescending(group => group.Count());

                lstMostPopularCourse.Items.Add(popular.First());


            }

            sr.Close();
}


private void btnPopularCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"R:\Data.txt");
            string line = string.Empty;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                lstMostPopularCourse.ClearSelected();
                string[] col = line.Split(',');

                var popular = (from item in col[0]
                group item by item into gr
                orderby gr.Count() descending
                select gr.Key).First();

                lstMostPopularCourse.Items.Add(popular);

            }

           sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is what you are looking for

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var nameList = new List<string>();
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"YOUR PATH"))
    {
        var data = line.Split(',');
        nameList.Add(data[0]);
    }

    var mostFrequentName = nameList.GroupBy(x => x)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
        .Select(g => g.Key)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should [separate your concerns](https://blog.ndepend.com/separation-of-concerns-explained/). Separate the way you get the data (read from a CSV-file), the way you process the data (find the most popular occurance of the first column), and the way you display the date (put into the display item, which in this case is a listbox)

Separation of concerns has several advantages:

- Because your code focuses on one subject it will be better understandable.
- The code will be easier to test without the overhead of the other concerns.
- The code can be re-used. You can use the CSV-file reading to fill other items, for instance a table
- If one of the concerns changes, for instance you read your data from a database instead of from a CSV-file, you won't have to change a lot of code.

You said you had a LINQ problem, so I guess you won't have a problem reading your input data. You'll have code like:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime Dob {get; set;}
    public bool Male {get; set;}
    public int Age => (DateTime.Now - this.Dob).Years // almost correct, TODO: repair
}

IEnumerable<Person> ReadPersons() {...}  // reads from your input file
```

Similarly you'll have some function that Adds a Person to the object that shows Persons to the operator. In your case a ListBox, but since we separated the concerns, we don't care. After all, you said you mastered adding it.

```
void DislayName(string name) {... add name to the listbox }
```

Now all you have to do is create a function that selects the name of the Person you want to Display.

```
string SelectNameToDisplay(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    TODO: implement
}

private void btnPopularCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     IEnumerable<Person> persons = ReadPersons();
     string nameToDisplay = SelectNameToDisplay(persons);
     DisplayName(nameToDisplay);
}
```

You indicated that you had no problem reading the persons and displaying the name, so all we have to do is selecting the right name

I added ...OrDefault, in case there are no persons

```
string SelectNameToDisplayOrDefault(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    // TODO: exception if persons equals null

    // select the person with the name that occurs most
    // group them by name, and count the number of persons in each group
    // finally take the group with the largest number of persons

    var mostUsedName = persons
        .GroupBy(person => person.Name,       // KeySelector
            (name, personsWithThisName) => new // ResultSelector
            {
                Name = name,
                Count = personsWithThisName.Count(),
            })

         // order such that the person that occurs most comes first
         .OrderByDescending(person => person.Count)
         // keep only the name:
         .Select(person => person.Name)
         // and take the first one
         .FirstOrDefault();
     return mostUsedName;             
}
```

Although this will do the job in one LINQ statement, it is a bit of a waste of processing power to sort all Persons by Count if you only need the one Person that comes first after sorting. I would change the procedure slightly:

```
string SelectNameToDisplayOrDefault(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    var personsWithCount = persons
        .GroupBy(person => person.Name,       // KeySelector
            (name, personsWithThisName) => new // ResultSelector
            {
                Name = name,
                Count = personsWithThisName.Count(),
            });

    // get the person that has the highest count, enumerating only once:
    var personEnumerator = personsWithCount.GetEnumerator();
    if (personEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // there is at least one Person:
        var mostOftenCountedPerson = personEnumerator.Current;

        // check if other persons have a higher count:
        while (personEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            // there is a next Person; does he have a higher Count?
            if (personEnumerator.Current.Count > mostOftenCountedPerson.Count)
            {
                 // yes this person is counted more often
                 mostOftenCountedPerson = personEnumerator.Current;
            }
        }

        // enumerated the sequence exactly once, and we know the Person that is counted most
        return mostOftenCountedPerson;
    }
    else
    {   
        // no person at all; TODO: decide what to do
    }
}
```

Comment: If I create the IEnumerable<Person> persons to include all the columns from the text file, how would I then output the oldest person with all their info for example?

Comment: Until now you said you wanted the **name** of a Person, now you want to show a **Person** instead of only the name. The idea is separation: separate the input, the process and the output. Create an output class that accepts a Person and shows what you want to show from that person. The LINQ statement to select the eldest person from a sequence of Person is a simple OrderBy and FirstOrDefault.  Not possible to write that in a Comment, it is a new question